# Why is the user being set to null after I refresh the Web page from the browser?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have been working on authentication for a React - Redux based app and facing an issue with state persistence.

When I login, the user gets set correctly, however, when I refresh the browser, the user goes to null, **even though it is present in the localStorage**.

This problem occured after I did some tweaks with this useEffect hook:

```
const [tempCode, setTempCode] = useState(null)
const { user, isSuccess, message } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSuccess && user) {
      dispatch(reset())
      navigate("/")
    } else {
      const queryString = window.location.search
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString)
      const codeExists = urlParams.get("code")

      if (codeExists) {
        setTempCode({ code: codeExists })
      }
      dispatch(login(tempCode))
      navigate("/")
    }
  }, [tempCode])
```

Here's the initial state from auth slice:

```
const initialState = {
  isSuccess: false,
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
  message: "",
}
```

Here's the reset action from the auth reducer:

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false
      state.isError = false
      state.isSuccess = false
      state.message = ""
    },
```

Why is the user being reset to null when it's still present in local storage? It was working fine previously.

Comment: Can you print the whole `state` to check what it is after you refresh the page?

Comment: After I refresh the browser, the user state becomes null in the Redux state.

Comment: So, you tell me why the user state becomes `null`?

Comment: It got fixed! I removed isSuccess from if (isSuccess && user)  and it worked correctly!